# Is there a js-algorand-sdk equivalent of eth-subscribe?

Tags: javascript, logging, algorand

I want to subscribe to a smart contract logging using something similar to `eth_subscribe`. I'm using Algorand's JS SDK. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is `lookupApplicationLogs(appID: number): default`

[Source](https://algorand.github.io/js-algorand-sdk/classes/_internal_.LookupApplicationLogs.html)